# Удаление слов с определенными символами

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Необходимо из строки удалить слова, содержащие все определенные символы.

Например, если строка `1234 445 665 114 1324`, а набор символов - `1` и `2`, то остаться должно только `445 665 114`.

Я собираюсь сделать это с помощью регулярного выражения. Не могу придумать выражение, исключая перечисления различных комбинаций порядка символов.

```
s = re.sub(r'<REGEXP>', '', s)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться Positive Lookahead

```
\b(?=\d*1)\b(?=\d*2)\d+ ?
```

[**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/jLubQ9/1)

Comment: А если требуется удалить только то, что содержит буквы и точку? (К примеру из строки "fbv.ccf qqaz xxsd. ccd.qq. aa.aa.a .ddd.f qqq" должна получиться "qqaz qqq"). Не могу преобразовать Ваше выражение:( @splash58

Comment: `\b(?=\S*[a-zA-Z])\b(?=\S*\.\d+ ?`